# jhipster app gives different eTLD+1 error (angular 2+ and mysql app)

Tags: angular, jhipster

I have generated jhipster monolith app with MySql back end and Angular 2 (latest version) using jhipster online app generator. When I run the app in spring tool suite, I have got message :

```
Application 'sample' is running! Access URLs:
    Local:      http://localhost:8080
    External:   http://10.189.116.206:8080
    Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
```

But in my browser when I try to access, localhost:8080, I am getting the message saying, your request can't be processed [image: error]
 and in the console I have the warning:

```
fixurl.js:149 A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, https://linkhelp.clients.google.com/tbproxy/lh/wm?sourceid=wm&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&hl=en&site=localhost%3A8080&error=http404&js=true, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
pb @ fixurl.js:149
```

In my project noticed under node modules the following file shows an error message

```
/sample/node_modules/@schematics/angular/application/files/__dot__angular-cli.json
```

at

```
 }<% if (serviceWorker) { %>,
      "serviceWorker": true<% } %>
    }
```

and the error message is,

```
Expected ',' or '}' at 29:7
```

I have not made any changes in this file till now. But still I am getting this error message.

Can any one help me on this how to get it fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dev you must run mvnw/gradlew (java server) **and** yarn/npm start (webpack server) and then your browser will open up webpack url. See http://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/ and your project README.md

Comment: I don't want to use yarn and I already have working npm in my system. Is it necessary that I need to install yarn? Even while generating the application I have not given yarn option.